# Why is a cast needed when a closure is passed as a trait object argument?

Tags: rust, closures, traits

I'm trying to create a trait that should abstract over functions/closures with a different number of arguments. Something like this:

```
trait MyTrait {}

impl MyTrait for Box<Fn() -> &'static str> {}

impl MyTrait for Box<Fn(u8) -> u8> {}
```

Initially I planned to use it like this:

```
fn myf<F: MyTrait>(_fun: F) {}

fn main() {
    myf(Box::new(|i: u8| i + 2))
}
```

But this code fails with error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<[closure@src/main.rs:11:18: 11:31]>: MyTrait` is not satisfied
```

When I cast the box like this, everything compiles correctly:

```
myf(Box::new(|i: u8| i + 2) as Box<Fn(_) -> _>)
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=9c774d4ca5057e424f0a9f823c61b149&version=stable&mode=debug)

Why can't the Rust compiler infer this trait without a cast? Is my approach (using cast) correct, or is there a simpler way? I prefer to enable `trivial_casts` warning for my projects and this syntax triggers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a thing that one tends to forget: each closure is a different struct that implements `Fn`: `Fn` is a trait, not a struct, and trait implementations are not transitive.

Here is a little example that shows this point:

```
trait Base {}
trait Derived {}
struct Foo {}

impl Base for Derived {}

impl Derived for Foo {}

fn myf<T>(_t: Box<T>)
where
    T: Base + ?Sized,
{
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Box::new(Foo {});
    //myf(foo) // does not compile
    myf(foo as Box<Derived>)
}
```

The thing you really wanted to do is:

```
trait MyTrait {}

impl<T> MyTrait for T
where
    T: Fn() -> &'static str,
{
}

impl<T> MyTrait for T
where
    T: Fn(u8) -> u8,
{
}

fn myf<F>(_fun: Box<F>)
where
    F: MyTrait,
{
}

fn main() {
    myf(Box::new(|i: u8| i + 2))
}
```

But this cannot compile because there are two conflicting implementations.